# How to check if a windows service created using JavaService.exe has correctly executed method without error

Tags: java, exception, windows-services

I created a windows service using JavaService. Then, I started it through my java application by calling command "net start MyService".

My problem is that the called method to start service has thrown a java exception but windows services manager has not detected it and the service status became started.

The question is how could I get the information from windows services manager that there was a java exception when calling method of starting/stopping service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to get that information(java exception when calling start method) from windows services.

we can only install/start/stop/delete a windows service, no more!!